# Address Complex numbers and create new matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, output, complex-numbers

I have a complex matrix of size *3x2x372 complex double*. I would like to work with only one specific of these three dimensions. Therefore, I used the following code to make the table easier to read:

```
new_output = abs(output);
```

In fact, the new matrix is of size *3x2x372 double*. I guess it makes the further computation simpler. So I obtain the following output:

[image]

I would now like to create a matrix that only refers to the highlighted values. So it should ideally be of size *2x372 double*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a for-loop and assign the last row to a new matrix.

```
mat = zeroes(372, 2)

for k = 1:372
    a = val(:, :, k)
    mat(k, :) = a(1, :)
end
```

Edit: above gives you a 372x2 matrix. Use below to get a 2x372 matrix

```
mat = zeroes(2, 372)
```

And

```
mat(:, k) = a(1,:).'
```

in the loop

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need the last row from each "slice", so you can get it by:

```
new_output=data(size(data,1),:,:);
```

But that will give you the same dimensions as the original matrix, with 3D. To directly get it as 2D matrix, use `squeeze`:

```
new_output=squeeze(data(size(data,1),:,:));
```